# Post запрос из js на php

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch, formdata

Я пытаюсь отправить запрос на мой php файл, в нетворке все нормально, запрос идет, данные отправляются, но переменная `$ _POST` пустая, что я делаю не так?
Мой код:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
  const form = document.querySelector('form')
  form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    fetch('form.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new FormData(form)
    })
  })
</script>
<?php
  print_r($_POST) // empty
?>
```

Если писать вот так, то все работает правильно, данные попадают в переменную

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: консоль разработчика откройте и посмотрите на перечень ошибок. в нетворке заметьте у вас отправка не xhr а обычный get (а не post), при этом наверняка страница у вас перезагружается при отправке формы. и в адресной строке браузера получается `?name=.....`

Comment: Метод post указан же, да и preventDefault. Вы внимательно читали?

Comment: Что-то я не вижу где вы выводите результат вызова fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, названных умников много... А помочь никто не помог.

Используйте следующий вариант(протестировал):

```php
<?php
?>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="123">
    <button formmethod="post">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    console.log(form);
    form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        fetch('form.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new FormData(form)
        }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
        });
    })
</script>
```

Второй файл:

```php
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
print_r($_POST);
```

Для отладки, можно добавить сохранение в файл.

```php
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
print_r($_POST);
$file = 'text.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents($file, $_POST);
```

Скрины:
Файл 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл 2 называется `help16.php`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вводим данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После ввода открываем файл `text.txt`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, если вернуть response.text(), показывает все правильно, но на другой вкладке в файле form.php, переменная $_POST все равно пустая

Comment: @RavenTheX Попробуйте, пожалуйста, сначала мой код. Данные приходят. Чтобы дополнительно отследить попробуйте добавить сохранение в файл этого `$_POST`. Протестировал - точно работает.

Comment: Может быть мы говорим о разных вещах, но у меня ваш код не работает. Использую apache xampp

Comment: @RavenTheX Добавил скрины обоих файлов и их выполнение. Проверьте, пожалуйста, что у Вас всё точно так же.

Comment: @RavenTheX Все 3 файла лежат в одной директории.

Comment: В текст.txt запись появляется, но попробуйте вывести $_POST в другом php файле, она пустая, и запись с текстового файла пропадает после перезагрузки, не понятно как тогда с ней работать

Comment: @RavenTheX А как Вы передаёте параметр в третий файл? Да нет, не удаляется, всё сохраняется в файле. Проверил.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104825/discussion-between-raventhex-and-denis640kb).